# Why float left does not work as expected here?

Tags: css

I expected the images were on the right of the list, but no..

```
<main class="works">
    <div class="izq">
      <nav>
                <li><a class="" href="/app_dev.php/works/35">eeeee</a></li>
                <li><a class="" href="/app_dev.php/works/36">fasdf</a></li>
      </nav>
    </div>
    <section>
        <img src="http://www.seobook.com/images/smallfish.jpg">
        <img src="http://www.seobook.com/images/smallfish.jpg">
    </section>
</main>



.works {
    width: 600px;
}
div {
   float: left;   
}
section {
    float: left;
}
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/K72NA/)

Answer (score 2):

```
.works {
    width: 600px; <--- not enough space to maintain float
}
```

Seems to be the issue- there is not enough space allocated to maintain a float, [see adjusted fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/K72NA/4/), namely that 600px is not enough horizontal space to 'fit' the images in when floated. Either increase or remove the `600px` allocation.

Comment: Please check the fiddle again- the CSS for .works has been removed

Comment: and its still the same.. i mean issue still there.

Comment: Increase the width of your browser window

Comment: No worries, not at all :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide width to your `.section` class

**Lab:** [labs.codeteam.in/lab/PBDAedPvVki~Mu1eYT4AqndZUOdeapGx](http://www.labs.codeteam.in/lab/PBDAedPvVki~Mu1eYT4AqndZUOdeapGx)